# If condition that pushes values that contain/match a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, fullcalendar, string-matching

I have a nicely functioning full calendar script. I have some filters for it, which basically have the following form:

```
$("input[name='event_filter_select']:checked").each(function () {
    // I specified data-type attribute in HTML checkboxes to differentiate
    // between risks and tags.
    // Saving each type separately
    if ($(this).data('type') == 'risk') {
        risks.push($(this).val());
    } else if ($(this).data('type') == 'tag') {
        tagss.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

However the `else if` statement should check if the checked value 'tag' is contained within the result set, not be the only value of the result set (as implied by the `==`).

Now I can only filter results that have the checked tag-value only. But i want to filter those, which have the tag-value amongst many others.

I figure this is to be done with `match(/'tag'/)` but i cannot figure out for the life of me how to put that into an if-statement.

Would be really glad if someone could lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you describe the output you want a little more - it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: " to filter those, which have the tag-value amongst many others" - use separated `if` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
...
if ($(this).data('type') == 'risk') {
    risks.push($(this).val());
} else if ($(this).data('type').test(/^tag/) {
    tagss.push($(this).val());
}
...
```

This works if the 'tag' must be at the beginning of the string.
If the 'tag' can be everywhere in the string, you can use `test(/tag/)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this condition.

```
   /\btag\b/.test($(this).data('type'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a string, example: `tag filter1 filter2 filter3`, you could use the `indexOf`-function ([manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf))

Code:

```
if ($(this).data('type').indexOf("risk") != -1))
   //Action here.
```

`indexOf` returns `-1` if the text isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i');
```

or if you wish to have the word hard-coded in (e.g., in the example, the word *test*):

```
var re = /\btest\b/i
```

Example showing the matches below:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var re;
var match;

input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  match = input.value.trim();
  re = new RegExp('\\b' + match + '\\b', 'i');
  
  if($('div').data('type').match(re))
    div.innerHTML = 'Matched the word: ' + '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
  else div.innerHTML = 'Did not match the word: ' + '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Word to match:<input></input><br>
Output:
<div data-type='tag tags test'></div>
```

With the above regular expression incorporated into your code, it should look something like this:

```
else if ($(this).data('type').match(/\btag\b/i) { //true for data-type that has `tag` in it.
    tagss.push($(this).val());
}
```